# JSoup, Extract specific text or image-link from website

Tags: image, jsoup, extract

This is in my HTML and I need to extract either the link of the image or the fileId to create a link.

```
{
      "created": "2018-11-06T06:46:21.181Z",
      "inRiverId": "58515",
      "mediaInformation": {
        "bildid": 67708,
        "description": "ABC",
        "excelImportField": "ABC",
        "fileId": "41964",
        "filename": "ABC",
        "imageAccess": true,
        "imageItemType": "ABC",
        "imageStatus": "ABC",
        "imageType": "ABC",
        "itcl": "ABC",
        "photographer": "ABC",
        "projectName": "ABC",
        "projectType": "Webb",
        "type": "Bild",
        "url": "https://static.john.com/images/products/41964.jpg"
      },
```

The fileId is dynamic, therefor is the link also dynamic depending on which article I'm visiting on my website. The link will always start with "https://static.john.com/images/products/" and then it adds the fileId and ".jpeg" automatically.

The code above is of course just a piece of the code on the website, so there is more images on it, so it needs to extract it specifically.

The dream would be if Jsoup could get this output:
"https://static.john.com/images/products/" + "fileId" + ".jpeg"

I'm a beginner in Android Studio, and crazy-new to JSoup.

Comment: Jsoup Parsing and traversing a Document: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for the reply! I've just updated the post to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news. Jsoup can't do this. Jsoup parses only HTML but this is a JSON fragment which will be used by Javascript after the page is loaded in the browser.
However my idea is to get this URL using regular expressions so try using this code:

```
String json = "{\n" + 
        "      \"created\": \"2018-11-06T06:46:21.181Z\",\n" + 
        "      \"inRiverId\": \"58515\",\n" + 
        "      \"mediaInformation\": {\n" + 
        "        \"bildid\": 67708,\n" + 
        "        \"description\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"excelImportField\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"fileId\": \"41964\",\n" + 
        "        \"filename\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"imageAccess\": true,\n" + 
        "        \"imageItemType\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"imageStatus\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"imageType\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"itcl\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"photographer\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"projectName\": \"ABC\",\n" + 
        "        \"projectType\": \"Webb\",\n" + 
        "        \"type\": \"Bild\",\n" + 
        "        \"url\": \"https://static.john.com/images/products/41964.jpg\"\n" + 
        "      },";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"url\": \"(https://static.john.com/images/products/\\d+.jp[e]*g)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(json);
if (m.find()) {
    String imageUrl = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(imageUrl);
}
```

and the output is:  `https://static.john.com/images/products/41964.jpg`
In your case instead of `json` variable you should use `document.html()`.

Comment: Oh, man! That is just awesome! So JSoup will look for https://static.john.com/images/products/ and then copy whatever comes after as long as it ends with ".jpg" or ".jpeg". And print the whole link as a result. Am I reading it correct?

Comment: Correct except one thing. It's not Jsoup that extracts the data. Use Jsoup to download HTML code of the site but further image link extraction is performed using regular expression search which has nothind to do with Jsoup but it's a "programming feature".

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class JsoupGetImage {

    public void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

        // Get the article number from TextView to complete link
        String articlenumber = ((TextView) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.findViewById(R.id.holderArticle)).getText().toString();

        // My URL + article number
        String url = "https://www.john.com/api/v1.0/articles/" + articlenumber;

        // JSoup 
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        // Pattern - Find pattern using partial link
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"url\": \"(https://static.john.com/images/products/\\d+.jp[e]*g)\"");

        // Matcher - Find match in my URL from Pattern
        Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
        if (m.find()) {
            String imageUrl = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(imageUrl);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Does this look good or am I missing something. How do I get my ImageView to show the image of the created link?

Kind regards,
John